# Why does my react-native-firebase app crash on first start after install?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to build an app with react-native and firebase, and have hit a fair few installation issues along the way. Currently, my problem is that the app crashes immediately after its starts, on the first start after it is installed (either debug or release modes). Once killed and re-started it works normally.

There seems to be no specific error recorded in the logs. Using log messages to narrow the point of crash, it appears to be either:

- `Firebase.auth().signInAnonymouslyAndRetrieveData()`, or
- `doc_ref.get()` where `doc_ref` is the result of `Firebase.firestore().collection("profiles").doc(instance_id)`

depending on the call sequence.

In the above, "start" means doing

- either

  - react-native run-android
- or

  - cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
  - cd ..
  - react-native run-android --variant=release

Doing either of the above if the app is NOT already installed results in it starting and immediately crashing, but then appearing in the phone's list of installed apps. Repeating the above once the app is installed results in it working as intended.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Environment:

- laptop running Ubuntu 17.10
- Real Sony Xperia Z5 phone connected via USB
- node v6.11.4
- yarn v1.6.0
- react-native 0.55.3
- react-native-cli 2.0.1
- react-native-firebase 4.0.4

Relevant application code:

```
// Top level app component
export default class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
...
  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      IconFiles.load();
      StatusBar.setHidden(true);
      BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress",
        this.hardwareBackPress.bind(this));

      const that = this;
      this.setupProfile()
...
        .catch(function (err) {
          Log.error(`error in new App() end of promise chain: ${err}`);
          Crashlytics.recordError(1, err);
        });
```

...

```
export default class Profile {
...

  public static getProfile(): Promise<Profile> {
    const that = this;
    Log.debug(`getProfile() starting: ${RNFirebase.SDK_VERSION}`);
    return RNFirebase.auth().signInAnonymouslyAndRetrieveData()
      .then(function (blah) {
        Log.debug(`getProfile() signInAnonymouslyAndRetrieveData() return okay: ${blah}`);        
        return RNFirebase.iid().get()
      })
      .then(function (instance_id: string): Promise<Profile> {
        Log.debug(`getProfile() got instance id: ${instance_id}`);        
        const firestoreCollection: any
          = RNFirebase.firestore().collection("profiles");

        const doc_ref = firestoreCollection.doc(instance_id);
        Log.debug(`getProfile() got profile doc_ref: ${doc_ref.id}`);        
        return doc_ref.get();
      })
      .then(function (doc_snapshot: any /*Firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot*/) {
        Log.debug(`getProfile() got profile doc_snap: ${doc_snapshot.exists}`);        
        let data: Constrob;
        if (doc_snapshot.exists) {
          data = <Constrob>doc_snapshot.data();
        } else {
          data = {
            created_date: new Date(),
            feedback: null,
            starts: null,
            token: null,
          };
        }
        return new Profile(doc_snapshot.ref, data, doc_snapshot.exists);
      });
  }
```

...

package.json
...

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.12.0",
    "loglevel": "^1.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.2",
    "react-native-firebase": "^4.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.12.1",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-svg": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0"
  },
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2"
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

android/gradle.properties

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
android.enableAapt2=false
```

android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.doorkey"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.3"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":react-native-firebase")) {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1"
    implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:12.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1"
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? i am having similar issue after installing firebase.

Comment: No, I didn't. Ended up abandoning the react-native / firebase track owing to a series of issues like this, and reverted to plain react / webapp approach.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read this?

"If the GoogleService-Info.plist is not registered with XCode, your app will crash right after starting."

Read 'IOS Troubleshooting'
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/troubleshooting/ios

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with RN v0.55.4
the easiest solution is to update RN to v >=0.57 either using the [upgrade guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading) or your method of preference.
Also, if you are upgrading an ignite project, there is an incompatibility that also needs to be resolved, [see here](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite/issues/1313)